# Find all invertible elements of $ \Bbb{Q}[x]/(x^{600}) $.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know that invertible elements of $\Bbb{Q}[x]$ are constants, so $\Bbb{Q}$. But in $\Bbb{Q}[x]/(x^{600})$, I suppose there are more invertible elements. How to find all of them?

Comment: Can you find the invertible elements of $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^2)$? I think that's much easier and should help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT:

Show first that if $R$ is a commutative ring with identity with a unique maximal ideal $\frak m$ (such rings are called *local*) the invertible elements of $R$ are exactly the elements in $R\setminus\frak m$.

Now show that $\Bbb Q[X]/(X^N)$ has a unique maximal ideal for all $N\geq1$, namely the ideal generated by (the class of) $X$.

Comment: does that mean that the maximal ideal is (x) so that invertible elements are precisely Q[x]/(x) which is isomorphic to Q?

Comment: @stella : no, $R\setminus\frak m$ is the difference set, the elements in $R$ not in $\frak m$, not the quotient $R/\frak m$.

Comment: Ok, got it! Thank you.

Comment: @AndeaMori, I just came back to this question, and I am not sure how to describe these invertible elements. Are they all the polynomials in Q[x] excluding classes of polynomials with zero constant term?

Comment: @stella : exactly. The unique maximal ideal is that generated by $X$. An element in the quotient is represented by a unique polynomial of degree $\leq N-1$ which is invertible if and only if its constant term is not $0$.

Comment: @AndeaMori, that is great, I think I got it.